# Error when trying to request data from form. Flask - Python

Tags: python, flask

I have a html page where i have some forms where i write the crust, size and flavor of a pizza.
I try to get those data via request.form, but i get the error

'werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.'

I searched for it and most people would say it is because the form would be missing, or not maching the name. But i guess it is.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///pizza.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Order(db.Model):
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    crust = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    flavor = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    size = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Pedido %r>' % self.order_id

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        flavor = request.form['flavor']
        size = request.form['size']
        crust = request.form['crust']
        new_order = Order(crust=crust, flavor=flavor, size=size)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_order)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'error posting data...'
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Task Master</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="content">
    <h1 >Pizza Master</h1>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Sabor</th>
            <th>Tamanho</th>
            <th>Borda</th>
        </tr>
        <td>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="flavor" id="flavor" required>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="size" id="size" required>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="crust" id="crust" required>
            </form>
        </td>
    </table>
    <br>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Pedir pizza">
    </form>
    
    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing each of your form input with a separate <form> ... </form> wrapper. I do not know that this is wrong, but when I create forms, I place all inputs, plus the submit button, inside a single <form> element. It could be that you form cause an empty POST to be generated, which could be considered an illegal request.

Comment: Moving them all inside one <form> worked! Thanks man